# How can I create a line graph using ggplot if I don't have a header in the first column?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My code is below, where would I input the place for "x"? Also how would I do this if I wanted to linegraph multiple tickers in the same file showing in different columns?

ggplot(portfolioprices,aes(x = , y = INO)) + geom_line()

Here is what the data looks like:
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3fwd.png)

This is what I want it to look like but with labels:
[Graph produced with R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcgvF.png)

Comment: `ggplot(portfolioprices,aes(x = seq_along(INO), y = INO)) + geom_line()` (or using `seq_len(nrow(portfolioprices))`, same effect).

Answer (score 0):

Getting access to your data and the kind of graph you intend to plot made it easier for me to understand your objective and now I think I found a solution for your question. Try to reproduce the following code:

```
# load environment
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
# define dataframe
df = data.frame(
  date = c('1/3/2020', '1/6/2020', '1/7/2020', '1/8/2020', '1/9/2020'),
  ino = c(2.98, 3.14, 3.15, 3.14, 3.1),
  mrna = c(18.89, 18.13, 17.78, 17.98, 18.4),
  nio = c(3.83, 3.68, 3.24, 3.39, 3.46),
  fcntx = c(13.8, 13.92, 13.9, 14, 14.12)
)
# transform date strings to date class
df$date = dmy(df$date)
class(df$date)
# tidy the dataframe to plot it
df = melt(df, id.vars = 1, measure.vars = 2:5)
# plot the graph
ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = value, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.5) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 month', date_labels = '%m/%Y')
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Let me know if it is the graph you're looking for.

Comment: you can edit your last post and add the dataframe you've been using to plot those graphs. it's hard to reproduce your problem without any dataframe..

Comment: I can't embed images yet so it created a link if you can take a look?

Comment: That's great @ShreddedScientist! Now I'm able to help you. I edited my last answer, check it out.

Comment: How do I assign a date header to the date column if the file doesn't have it? The data that I am pulling from comes from the CSV file. This is my code below and it says the error: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, date, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 171

df = data.frame(portfolioprices)

transform date strings to date class
df$date = dmy(df$date)
class(df$date)

Comment: `df$date = dmy(df$date); class(df$date)` does exactly what you want, it transform 'character' objects into 'date'. you just have to install the library **lubridate** before (using `install.packages('lubridate')`) and then load the library (using `library(lubridate)`)